# iframe tag blocking other contents of the page

Tags: html, xhtml

I am a beginner in html. I have a web page containing an `iframe` tag.
If the tag is closed like

```
<iframe src="http://mysite.com/l/5042/2012-06-21/9pb4y" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border: 0" />
```

the html content following `iframe` tag are not displayed.
But if the tag is closed like

```
<iframe src="http://mysite.com/l/5042/2012-06-21/9pb4y" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border: 0" > </iframe>
```

everything works fine.

Don't know why I am having this weird issue.

Comment: Is it like `iframe` doesn't work with `<self closed tag/>` whereas it works when it is closed by `</close tag>`?

Comment: What is the DOCTYPE of the page?

Comment: @Karl: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`. The page is a `.jsp` page.

Answer (score 1):

Copy this code to the [W3C markup validation service](http://validator.w3.org/):

```
<!-- <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> //-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"> 
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <iframe src="http://mysite.com/l/5042//2012-06-21/9pb4y" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border: 0" ></iframe>

    <iframe src="http://mysite.com/l/5042//2012-06-21/9pb4y" width="100%" height="500" frameborder="0" style="border: 0" />

</body>
</html>
```

Comment and uncomment as appropriate to test the two different `DOCTYPE`s.

You will see that the `iframe` tag is not supported with your `DOCTYPE`. Either change the `DOCTYPE` or don't use `iframes`. (Of course, you can use the `iframe` tag that is explicitly closed, but since that does not validate, I would say that is a risky option if you want to work in as many browsers as possible.)

I don't mean to imply that `iframe` is deprecated. See this unchallenged posting on the [W3C site](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-html-editor/2008AprJun/0053.html)

Answer (score 0):

A iframe is tagged like the one that works in your example

`<iframe src=... attributes=...></iframe>`

But in your example is a space between open and close tag, just remove that.

Comment: My guess is that space is not causing any problem. In fact, please note this tip found on the w3shools.com site for their [iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) entry: _Tip: To deal with browsers that do not support <iframe>, place the text you want between the opening <iframe> tag and the closing </iframe> tag._

Comment: iFrame has a closing tag, like his 2nd example. That works. Maybe with or without space, but what browser nowadays that can display html don't support iframes (curious serious question)?